# Связь объектов в Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine2

1. Есть сущность Partner(Партнер)

   ```
   class Partner
       {
           /**
            * @ORM\Id
            * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
            * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
            */
           protected $id;

           /**
            * @ORM\Column(type="string")
            */
           protected $name;

           /**
            * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Service")
            * @ORM\JoinTable(name="partners_services",
            *     joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="partner_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
            *     inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="service_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
            *)
            */
           protected $services;
       }
   ```
2. Есть сущность Service(Услуга)

   ```
   class SubService
   {
       /**
        * @ORM\Id
        * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
        * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
        */protected $id;

       /**
        * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Service", inversedBy="subServices")
        * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="service_id", referencedColumnName="id")
        */
       protected $service;
   }
   ```
3. Есть сущность подуслуга

   ```
   class SubService
   {
       /**
        * @ORM\Id
        * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
        * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
        */protected $id;

       /**
        * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Service", inversedBy="subServices")
        * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="service_id", referencedColumnName="id")
        */
       protected $service;
   }
   ```

   У каждого партнера может быть набор услуг и под услуг
   К сущности Partner можно добавить полк subServices и сделать связь ManyToMany, но тогда затрудниться вывод полного дерева Услуги и их подуслуги.

Как можно прописать связь, что бы получать объекты так

```
$partner->getServices()->getSubServices()
```

Comment: Можете вопрос скорректировать, у вас представлены только классы SubService (два), а в маппингах, и там и там, указаны классы Service